# Value is not a valid XML regular expression

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

I am new to regular expressions and trying to validate an xml.  I keep getting the following errors:

1. Value `'^(?!\s+).{1,21}(?<!\s+)$'` is not a valid XML regular expression.

The first ? seems to be creating the error

2. Value `'\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2,4}(\s\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2}\s(am|Am|AM|pm|Pm|PM))?'` is not a valid XML regular expression.

The first / seems to be creating the error

3. Value `'^\w([\w|\s|\:\-]{0,18}\w)?$'` is not a valid XML regular expression.

The first : seems to be creating the error

4. Description: Value '1' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern `'^((V|v)?[1-9]|(N|n))$'` for type 'ReturnVersion'.
   Start location: 3:291

Thanks for the help.

Comment: 1) Do not use `^` and `$`, they are not metacharacters in XSD regex. 2) `(?!\s+)` is not supported.

Comment: Do not use regular expression to analyse XML, but the appropriate libraries. If validation is an issue, lxml might fit the bill.

Answer (score 1):

The rules for regular expressions in XML Schema are given in an appendix of the XSD 1.0 (or 1.1) specification. Unlike other parts of the W3C specification for XML Schema, they are reasonably readable. This regex dialect does not include the `^` and `$` anchors as meta-characters (they aren't needed because matching of the pattern facet is implicitly anchored), and it doesn't include any of the constructs starting with `(?`.

In your second regex, XSD doesn't allow characters that aren't meta-characters to be escaped, and this includes "/".

Some (so-called) XML Schema processors don't actually attempt to implement the regex rules correctly. The Microsoft .NET processor, for example, simply uses the .NET regex dialect. Not all developers realise that, so you may come across schemas that aren't portable to a different schema processor.